# Button click behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button on a page, when you click it, I want it to run a php script that makes an update behind the scenes. I don't want the page to change or anything.

I'm trying to adapt this code, which currently changes the page. If I can get this simplified example to work, I can adapt it from there. thanks

```
<input type="button" value="update" onclick="javascript: self.location='user.php?mode=add_phone&userid=904&phone=5555555555'"/>
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what AJAX is for; https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will help you with this!

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $.get('user.php?mode=add_phone&userid=904&phone=5555555555');
});
```

Don't forget to put the `mybutton` id on `input`!

Look [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax.
And the jQuery implementation is a good one: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/